# Display array of images that are store outside the public_html

Tags: php

I want to display array of images as thumbnails in bootstrap, the images are stored outside the public directory or root. 
This is the code I used to display images before storing them outside the public directory.

```
<?php 
 foreach ($artist as $value) : ?>
 <div class="col-xm-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="info.php?id=<?php echo $value['uploads_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo trim($value['uploads_cover']); ?>"></a>
<div class="caption">
    <p><?php echo substr($value['title'], 0,29); ?></p>
    <hr>
    <p><?php echo substr($value['name'], 0,29); ?></p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach;
```

[image]
Now I have decided to store images outside the web root, I can't display them with `foreach`, Currently I can display one image with the following code.

`image.php`

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
 readfile('/opt/lampp/htdocs/images/Uploads/00-cover.jpg.png');
```

then in my `src`

```
<img src="image.php" alt="..." >
```

**UPDATE Using suggested answer by Amarnasan**

```
 <?php foreach ($images as $value) : ?>
 <li>
<a href="image.php?folder=<?php echo $artist[0]['upload_folder'].'&img='.$value;?>">
            <img src="image.php?folder=<?php echo $artist[0]['upload_folder'].'&img=th_'.$value;?>" alt="<?php echo $artist[0]['title'];?>"  />
      </a>
    </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And my new `image.php` **It's working after removing extensions.** `. '.jpg.png'`

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  readfile('/opt/lampp/htdocs/images/'. $_GET['folder'] . '/' . $_GET['img']);
```

Images are still not displaying, when I open dev console, image src displays `src="image.php?folder=armin&img=th_21570.jpg"`

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I can't display multiple images.

Comment: `00-cover.jpg.png` kind of a contradictive extension, wouldn't you say? and `Content-type: image/jpeg` with a `.png`?

Comment: I know i have changed it, this is giving me a headache. I have searched everywhere and all the tutorials shows how to display one image.

Comment: so, why are you using `$_GET['img'] . '.jpg.png')` ? are you wanting to use those as an array?

Comment: Someone suggested that I pass the image name as a parameter to `image.php`

Comment: Get rid of the `.png` => `$_GET['img'] . '.jpg');` that's IF your files are JPG and not PNG.

Comment: I got rid of the extensions `$_GET['img'])` and it's working now , how can i use content-type for different types of images? like `.png` and `.gif` while iterating the array.

Comment: Great, glad to see I was of help (solved), but that's a whole different ball game and "another/different" question in its own right ;-)

Comment: This means I'll have to convert all my images to `.jpg` to be able to display them.

Comment: Google "glob php foreach image jpg png" and you'll get some answers in there. You won't have to convert anything *if you do it right* ;-) cheers

Comment: Plus, I should have put in an answer about removing what you did to close the originally posted and revised question http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32739240/2 - That isn't how things are done on Stack ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- is it possible to detect content-type with `finfo` and pass that type as a parameter? like `image.php?folder=<?php echo $artist[0]['upload_folder'].'&img='.$value .'&type='. $type;?>`

Comment: [please post a new question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) I answered the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the image name as parameter to image.php:

```
<img src="image.php?img=00-cover" alt="..." >
<img src="image.php?img=01-cover" alt="..." >
```

and

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
 readfile('/opt/lampp/htdocs/images/Uploads/'.$_GET['img'].'.jpg.png');
```

Comment: The `Uploads` folder will change as I iterate the foreach, and what does `'.jpg.png'` do?

Comment: This is wide open to attack, abuse of the URL for the $_GET clause needs to be cleaned and verified before being plugged into the readfile.

Comment: @Martin Yes, and maybe the address of his root user is 123456. So what? I'm not creating a fool-proof script, I'm just showing he can get any image he wants using parameters with the script image.php. It's up to him to refine the script and make it as secure as the rest of his project.

Comment: yes, that's fair enough, but I think it's at least worth a mention that if OP uses this in a production environment, they should be aware that they will need to do work to make it more tamper/abuse proof. That's all.